# apply.weeky function is suddenly returning "'x' must be numeric" only when using "sum" or "colSums"

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, numeric, xts

I've been importing data from a csv, then putting it into a dataframe.  I then pad it, convert it to an XTS.  After that I use apply.weekly to break it down into weekly data.  The code is below.

```
library(padr)
library(xts)
library(tidyr)
library(seasonal)
library(forecast)]
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df <- data.frame(data$f1.date[1:831], data.$f1[1:831])  #create data frame
colnames(df)<- c('date', 'f1')
df$date <- (as.Date(df$date, format='%m/%d/%Y'))
df<-pad(df)  # add missing dates


df<-xts(df, order.by = df$date)
df$t1<-replace_na(df$f1,0)  # Add Zeros for NA vals

dtw<-apply.weekly(df$f1,FUN=colSums) # I've tried using sum, colSums and mean.  Mean works fine.
```

However, sum or colSums returns the following.

```
Error in FUN(x[(INDEX[y] + 1):INDEX[y + 1]], ...) : 'x' must be numeric
```

So far, my only thought was to try `df$t1<-as.numeric(df$t1)`, but that had no effect.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?  This exact script was working fine with the same csv file, and I don't think anything has changed.  All I can think is that some package didn't get loaded.

A sample of my data is below, the full version has approximately 800 rows.  I am working on making it reproducible now.

Using `dput(head(df))` gives me this.

```
structure(c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", "2010-01-04", 
"2010-01-05", "2010-01-06", " 1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(1262304000, 1262390400, 1262476800, 
1262563200, 1262649600, 1262736000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("date", "f1")))
```

I also edited it to change 't1' to 'f1' for consistency.

Thanks

Comment: # Hi mineralpoint, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you have a typo on your first line where you assign `df`. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(data[1:30,])`. You can edit your question and paste the output. You can surround it with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Copying the data from the `.csv` file doesn't help because we need to know exactly what the data structure is you're trying to work on. 2) You need to edit your original post to provide the data because comments have length and format limitations. If `df` is working, you could provide `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted what I got from using dput(head(df)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your column `f1` is of class character.

```
is.character(df$f1)
[1] TRUE
```

One approach would be to convert it to numeric within your `apply.weekly` call:

```
apply.weekly(df$f1,function(x){sum(as.numeric(x))})
           f1
2010-01-03  1
2010-01-06  0
```

The reason for all this is because `xts` class objects hold the data inside a matrix. And matrices in R can only have columns of one class.

Comment: Wow, that did it.  Thank you.  I'll look into dplyr and lubridate more.